# Windows batch split word

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to make a script for servers at work that connects by hostname. There are about 200 servers, and I'd like to have the script connect to a device falling under the hostname of the system it runs on.

Example: Say the hostname of a server is **lpmm01200**, where "lpmm01" is server 01 at location "200". A device at this location such as a work station might be "lwmm01200". The location number is always three digits, and I'd like to split the hostname to get the location number, and then pair it again with the desired device name the script will connect to.

I can print the hostname from a set variable as shown below in the code, but how I split this to get the trailing three digits is a mystery to me. Any help is appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%H IN ('hostname') DO SET hostnamevar=%%H
ECHO %hostnamevar%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [substring](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) as follow

```dos
@echo off
for /f %%h in ('hostname') do set hostnamevar=%%h

set "locationvar=%hostnamevar:~6%"
set "servervar=%hostnamevar:~4,2%"
set "devicevar=%hostnamevar:~0,4%"

echo device:%devicevar%, server: %servervar%, location: %locationvar%
```

Which this should give this output:

```dos
device:lpmm, server: 01, location: 200
```

Comment: The substring functionality definitely seems to be on the right track, but this still only prints out the desired location number. I want to be able to use this number for attaching it to the device name the script will connect to. So hostname "lpmm01200" needs to be split so "200" can be placed at the end of something like "lwmm01" to become the desired device to connect to.

Comment: Perfect. This helped set me on course. Ended up setting a var for "lwmm01" and then combining it with locationvar to get the whole hostname to connect to. Thanks again.